# How can I preprocess my data better? Help finding issues with the Dataset to improve accurracy

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, cart, accuracy, data-preprocessing

[The 'DATA' and my Jupyter notebooks can be found here](https://github.com/rohan260696/ML-Assignment.git)

Now my issue is that for my data-set I get an mean accuracy from grid search of 0.64  (I get different for other models, like for svm 0.75) but for the same model if I use the breast cancer data-set provided in the Sci-kit Learn library I get an mean accuracy of 0.95. breast cancer data-set is similar to my data-set and both are binary classifications.

Now I think that the problem must be with my data and therefore my models are under-fitting. I would like to know if that hypothesis is correct? and if it is what do I do with my data to improve my accuracy? or is there something wrong with the way I am doing this, if it is kindly point me to the right direction.

[you can find the above tried in an jupyter notebook called experiments here](https://github.com/rohan260696/ML-Assignment.git)

## DATA

[image: Data Example]
[image: Data Analysis features 1 to 12]
[image: Data Analysis Features 12 to 20]

I am building various ML models for classification task on this data-set using sklearn. For an example of the problem I am facing I am posting one the Models (decision trees)

## PRE PROCESSING

```py
df = data.copy()                     # create new data-frame from the original data for preprocessing     

df = df.drop(columns = ['F20'])      # remove F20 from data,to avoid imputation 

x = df.drop(columns=['Class'])       # select all attributes except class 

y = df.Class                         # select Class as output to the classifier

smt = SMOTETomek(random_state = 42)  # fixing random state for reproducibility of the model

X_smt, y_smt = smt.fit_sample(x, y) 

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-3,3))
scaler.fit_transform(X_smt.values.reshape(-1, 1))

x = X_smt
y = y_smt
```

## DECISION TREE

```py
def Build_tree(x,y):

   clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 42)   

   path = clf.cost_complexity_pruning_path(x, y) 

   ccp_alphas = np.ndarray.tolist(path.ccp_alphas)                                                        

   max_depth = list(range(3,15,1))                  

   parameter_grid = {    'ccp_alpha':ccp_alphas,
                         'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
                         'splitter': ['best', 'random'],
                         'max_depth': max_depth 
                    }

   cross_validation = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10) 

   grid_search = GridSearchCV ( clf, 
                                param_grid=parameter_grid, 
                                cv=cross_validation, 
                                n_jobs = -1) 
       grid_search.fit(x,y) 

       print('Average Accuracy of the model: {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_))  

       print('Best parameters: {}'.format(grid_search.best_params_))

       clf = grid_search.best_estimator_              

       return clf
```

Comment: Decision tree is weak learner.  If you add jewelers rouge to a rock crusher the gravel doesn't come out looking shiny.  If you have a strong learner, like an RF or a GBM, then extensive preprocessing can get much more extensive results.